# UITextField "Expected identifier" issue

Tags: objective-c, string, input, uitextfield

I'm new to obj-c and I'm trying to code a simple "inputs to plist" app. I have two inputs:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *costo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descrizione;
```

and I synthesize them in the .m file

```
@synthesize costo;
@synthesize descrizione;
```

then I have a function saveData() with:

```
NSNumber *newValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[costo.text intValue]];
[mutableDictCopy setObject:newValue forKey:[descrizione.text]];
```

this function works fine with **costo.text**, but then I get an "Expected identifier" error with **descrizione.text**. if I switch it with @"foo", all goes fine and it updates my plist. Where do I get wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the member and message syntaxes.  This is OK:

```
[descrizione text]
```

The following is also OK.  It means the same thing.

```
descrizione.text
```

This is not OK:

```
[descrizione.text]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use This

```
   [mutableDictCopy setObject:newValue forKey:descrizione.text];
```

instead of

```
[mutableDictCopy setObject:newValue forKey:[descrizione.text]];
```